# Positioning all subtitles of a vtt file over video rather than positioning cue by cue

Tags: css, html5-video, webvtt

I want all .vtt subtitles to be lifted upwards over my htmlVideoElement a bit because they are too low down in the video viewport. I've read loads of articles and they all use the same example which doesn't solve my problem.
I can position individual cues as follows

```
2
00:00:18.166 --> 00:00:20.083 line:70%
At the right we can see the...
```

But I don't want to have to add line:70% to a hundred cues, I want to style all cues globally. The following code changes the text colour and background for all cues but none of the attempts to reposition the subtitles work with this.

```
WEBVTT

STYLE
::cue {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, dimgray, lightgray);
  color: green;
  line:70%;
  position: 70%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: **(1)** Regarding `top` & `left` what happens if you use real numbers (not percentages)? What happens if you set style inside track tag? Like... `<track style="position: absolute; top: 10" src="yourFile.vtt">` . **(2)** Do you also set `position` in some parent / container Div (of the video tag) that might be overwriting the subtitle positioning...?

Comment: Thanks. I tried both suggestions but it didn't change the positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could add some JavaScript code, then you should try method below:

1 Add event handler:

```
const track = this.video.textTracks[0] //you should choose you text track
track.addEventListener('cuechange', onCueChange);
```

2 Update the properties of your cues:

```
function onCueChange(event) {
  const cues = event.currentTarget.cues;
  for (let i = 0; i < cues.length; i++) {
    cues[i].line = 0 
  }     
}
```

Here's the code block

```js
 window.onload = function() {
  let video = document.querySelector('video');
  const track = video.textTracks[0] //you should choose you text track
  track.addEventListener('cuechange', onCueChange);

  function onCueChange(event) {
    const cues = event.currentTarget.cues;
    for (let i = 0; i < cues.length; i++) {
      cues[i].line = 0 
    }       
  }
}
```